# c# installshield wizard changes behavior of program

Tags: c#, installshield-le

I wrote a program, that monitors a device that is connected to a serial port.
When I use the compiled release version directly, everything works properly. I used Installshield LE to create an installer for this tool and in the installed version some parts of my code are not working or seem to be missing.

For example:

```
string[] getSerialData(string command, int expectedlength)
{
    string[] Ausgabe = { "" };

    while (Ausgabe.Length != expectedlength && run)
    {
        if (IPS_Port.IsOpen)
            IPS_Port.Write(command);


        try
        {
           Ausgabe = IPS_Port.ReadTo("\t").ToString().Split(splitString, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            j++;

            if (j >= 8)
            {
               notico.ShowBalloonTip(30000,"Error","You lost connection to your IPS \"" + IPSname + "\"!",ToolTipIcon.Error);
               logWriter = new StreamWriter("ErrorLog.log",true);
               logWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss tt") + "(" + IPSname + "): Connection Lost!");
               logWriter.Close();
               lostConnection = true;
               reset();
               break;
            }

           continue;
       }
   }

   j = 0;
   return Ausgabe;
}
```

It proceeds until `notico.ShowBallonTip` and gets stuck there (shows the balloontip over and over again) but never reaches the logwriter part nor the `reset()` command.

Why does this happen and how do I solve this?

Comment: Does "Error.log" ever get created? Because if not then my bet would be on your application having no permission to write "ErrorLog.log" (which probably will be located in application installation directory).

Comment: I agree with @KubaWyrostek since you do not give a path name for the `StreamWriter` constructor, but only a file name it will most probably trying to write in the `C:\Program Files\My Company\My App` directory, which, unless you have changed its security permissions, will not be writeable by your application.

Comment: Agree with @KubaWyrostek and @Übercoder; aside from that: installers don't change the behaviour of a program; they simply copy files, add registry entries etc. Always look for a bug in your *own* code (in these kinds of cases) **first** before blaming a framework or external source which (usually) has a much bigger installbase and is (usually) much better tested.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, @Übercoder, @Roblll thanks for your hints. Right now i'm looking how to set security permissions for my tool via `SetAccessControl` but it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. I have full administrator access at my computer. Do you have any ideas what could cause this exception?